# Infragistics DockManager - flickering when showing a floating view in the dockworkspace

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I am using the infragistics UltraDockManager to show a floating - screen centered view in the Dockworspace, the problem that, when showing the view in the center it is flickering and user can see the view when moving from the default location to the center location

How can I get rid of this behavior?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found here : http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/41561.aspx